# How would I prove that the interval $[0, 1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am studying measure theory and looking for how to prove this. I would like to achieve this without the use of measure theory.

Comment: Use that the union of a finite or countable collection of countable sets is countable. So if the union is uncountable ...

Comment: Suppose to the contrary that $[0, 1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is countable, where $f : \mathbb{N} \to [0, 1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is a surjection, and let $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ be another surjection (which we know exists). Then set $h(2k - 1) = f(k), h(2k) = g(k)$. We thus get a surjection $h : \mathbb{N} \to \left( [0, 1] \setminus \mathbb{Q} \right) \cup \mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $[0, 1]$ is countable.

Comment: If $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ were countable, $[0,1]$ would be countable too (the union of two countable sets is countable), but $[0,1]$ is not countable by Cantor's diagonal argument.

Answer (score 4):

First, we show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and that the interval $[0,1]$ is uncountable.

Once we have shown these facts, then we assume that $[0, 1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

But then $$[0, 1] = \left( [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q} \right) \cup \left( [0, 1] \setminus \mathbb{Q} \right).$$

Finally, we show that the union of any two (or finitely many!) countable sets is countable, and so is any (infinite) subset of a countable set, thus arriving at a contradiction.

Comment: Sums it up nicely~

Comment: Well, $[0,1] = (\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]) \cup ([0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q})$.  $2$ certainly isn't in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

We can find an uncountable subset of $[0,1]\backslash \mathbb{Q}$. Here's a suggestion. Collect all numbers with specified decimal expansion:
For any $0,1$ sequence $a=(a_n)$, define

$$
b_{a}=0.b_1 b_2 b_3 \cdots b_n \cdots,
$$
where $b_i=0$ if $i\neq  n!$, $i\neq n!+1$, $n\geq 2$ and 
$b_{n!}=1$, $b_{n!+1}=a_n$, $n\geq 2$.

Collection of all such numbers is uncountable because it contains a copy of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Added: This set also provides an example of a perfect set consisted entirely of irrational numbers.